# Web3 Issue : React Application not compiling

Tags: javascript, reactjs, create-react-app, web3js

I am facing issue with React application while compilation.
Please find the issue below and screenshot.

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/web3-providers-http/lib/index.js 30:11-26
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'http' in '/Users/rohit/Downloads/Personal/web3/react-minting-website/node_modules/web3-providers-http/lib'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
        - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "http": require.resolve("stream-http") }'
        - install 'stream-http'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
        resolve.fallback: { "http": false }
 @ ./node_modules/web3-core-requestmanager/lib/index.js 56:16-46
 @ ./node_modules/web3-core/lib/index.js 23:23-58
 @ ./node_modules/web3/lib/index.js 32:11-31
 @ ./src/index.js 10:0-24 14:13-17
```

[image: React-app-issue]

On scrutiny, I found out Issue is with web3 related dependencies :

```
https://www.npmjs.com/package/web3
https://www.npmjs.com/package/@web3-react/core
https://www.npmjs.com/package/@web3-react/injected-connector
```

Can someone please help me with the same? I am using LTS versions, What are stable versions of these?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Webpack 5 Errors - Cannot Resolve 'crypto', 'http', and 'https' in ReactJS Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70429654/webpack-5-errors-cannot-resolve-crypto-http-and-https-in-reactjs-proje)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

as webpack grows in size, they removed the polyfills in webpack5. Looks like you are using create-react-app (CRA) and webpack configuration is not exposed to the user in CRA. you can expose it using `eject`. you might have this script in package.json:

```
   "eject": "react-scripts eject"
```

so run `npm run eject`. This is not recommended because it means that you will no longer benefit from the updates of CRA.

you can handle ejecting with either [rewire](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rewire) or [craco](https://www.npmjs.com/package/craco).

After you get the webpack configuration, you need to add `resolve` property to webpack config and  install all those required packages :

```
resolve: {
    extensions: [".js", ".css"],
    alias: {
      // add as many aliases as you like!
      // optional
      components: path.resolve(__dirname, "src/components"),
    },
    fallback: {
      // path: require.resolve("path-browserify"),
      fs: false,
      assert: require.resolve("assert/"),
      os: require.resolve("os-browserify/browser"),
      constants: require.resolve("constants-browserify"),
      stream: require.resolve("stream-browserify"),
      crypto: require.resolve("crypto-browserify"),
      http: require.resolve("stream-http"),
      https: require.resolve("https-browserify"),
    },
  },
```

I have `webpac5 Boilerplate`. you can use it if you want:

- Since there are too many polyfills, instead of manually installing all,  you can use [node-polyfill-webpack-plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/craco) package. instead of `fallback` property

  ```
   const NodePolyfillPlugin = require("node-polyfill-webpack-plugin");

  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      title: "esBUild",
      template: "src/index.html",
    }),
    // instead of fallback
    new NodePolyfillPlugin(),

    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      process: "process/browser",
      Buffer: ["buffer", "Buffer"],
      React: "react",
    }),
  ],
  ```

[webpack5 boilerplate github repo](https://github.com/yilmazbingo/webpack5-Boilerplate)

Answer (score 7):

web3.js has updated their readme to included troubleshooting steps. Ref. [link](https://github.com/ChainSafe/web3.js#troubleshooting-and-known-issues).

#### Web3 and Create-react-app

If you are using create-react-app version >=5 you may run into issues building. This is because NodeJS polyfills are not included in the latest version of create-react-app.

#### Solution

- Install react-app-rewired and the missing modules

If you are using yarn:

```bash
yarn add --dev react-app-rewired process crypto-browserify stream-browserify assert stream-http https-browserify os-browserify url buffer
```

If you are using npm:

```bash
npm install --save-dev react-app-rewired crypto-browserify stream-browserify assert stream-http https-browserify os-browserify url buffer process
```

- Create `config-overrides.js` in the root of your project folder with the content:

```js
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = function override(config) {
    const fallback = config.resolve.fallback || {};
    Object.assign(fallback, {
        "crypto": require.resolve("crypto-browserify"),
        "stream": require.resolve("stream-browserify"),
        "assert": require.resolve("assert"),
        "http": require.resolve("stream-http"),
        "https": require.resolve("https-browserify"),
        "os": require.resolve("os-browserify"),
        "url": require.resolve("url")
    })
    config.resolve.fallback = fallback;
    config.plugins = (config.plugins || []).concat([
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            process: 'process/browser',
            Buffer: ['buffer', 'Buffer']
        })
    ])
    return config;
}
```

- Within `package.json` change the scripts field for start, build and test. Instead of `react-scripts` replace it with `react-app-rewired`

before:

```js
"scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
},
```

after:

```js
"scripts": {
    "start": "react-app-rewired start",
    "build": "react-app-rewired build",
    "test": "react-app-rewired test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
},
```

The missing Nodejs polyfills should be included now and your app should be functional with web3.

- If you want to hide the warnings created by the console:

In `config-overrides.js` within the `override` function, add:

```js
config.ignoreWarnings = [/Failed to parse source map/];
```

If you are using create-react-app version >=5 you may run into issues building. This is because NodeJS polyfills are not included in the latest version of create-react-app.

---

Currently CRA ships `react-scripts` with version `5.0.0`. Instead of ejecting CRA, just downgrade `react-scripts` to version `4.0.3`. I was facing the same issue, downgrading worked for me.

First remove old version

```
npm uninstall react-scripts
```

Then run the following:

```
npm i react-scripts@4.0.3
```

Comment: This answer would be improved by including the information behind the link at the top rather than just linking to it. When that page is down, the link loses any value.

Answer (score 1):

**Web3 and Create-react-app**
If you are using create-react-app version >=5 you may run into issues building. This is because NodeJS polyfills are not included in the latest version of create-react-app.

Refer the Solution in the Below link

**https://github.com/ChainSafe/web3.js#troubleshooting-and-known-issues**

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30893834)