# Multiple issues with webpack, polyfill and node modules

Tags: reactjs, webpack, node-modules, create-react-app, solidity

I am trying to build a simple react app calling a smart contract, however while running - I get multiple issues with webpack, node modules.
Most of the issues are pointing to resolve error
This react app was created with the create-react-app module.
Here are the errors

```
ERROR in ../node_modules/cipher-base/index.js 3:16-43

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'stream' in 'C:\Sandip@IBM\BlockChainDev\MultiSigWallet\node_modules\cipher-base'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.
```

Similarly the other errors

```
ERROR in ../node_modules/eth-lib/lib/bytes.js 7:193-227

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in 
ERROR in ../node_modules/swarm-js/node_modules/eth-lib/lib/bytes.js 9:193-227
ERROR in ../node_modules/web3-eth-accounts/lib/index.js 33:74-91

ERROR in ../node_modules/web3-providers-http/lib/index.js 30:11-26

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'http' in
```

I am bit lost on how to resolve these dependecy errors.

Thanks

Comment: check the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70472965/web3-issue-react-application-not-compiling/70512623#70512623

Answer (score 2):

If my guess is correct, you are using `react-script 5.0 +`
please use `"react-scripts": "4.0.3",`
that issue is because of webpack config.
there are several way to fix that problem but I think this way is simple solution.

Comment: where do I need to change the version? How do I downgrade the version of react?

Comment: just edit package.json and npm install. this will automatically downgrade react-script version

Comment: thanks...I modifed the version and ran npm install within the client folder...now the npm server won't start, getting some other errros like -- There might be a problem with the project dependency tree.
It is likely not a bug in Create React App, but something you need to fix locally.

The react-scripts package provided by Create React App requires a dependency:

  "webpack": "4.44.2"

Comment: what is your react version?

Comment: "_id": "react@17.0.2",

Comment: what node modules are you using in package.json?

Comment: This is what I have in the package.json -->   "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.1",
    "@testing-library/react": "^12.1.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-scripts": "^4.0.3",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4",
    "web3": "^1.7.0"
  },

Comment: I think I know what is the issue. There is another version of webpack higher up the tree, (part of node_modules for the truffle project) ..but I do not know how to fix it

Comment: I can't see webpack on your package.json.

Comment: @BlockChainLearner did this issue ever get solved?