# How to render a decentralized react application (Dapp): how to solve "Failed to parse source map from..."?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, solidity, web3js

I'm trying to build a decentralized app for a lottery smart contract, deployed on a local ganache ethereum network, for this I have created a project with `creat-react-app`.

This is the smart contract, it's pretty simple, it has pickWinner, enter and getPlayers functions.

```
contract Lottery {
    address public manager;
    address payable[] public players;
    uint256 index;

    constructor() payable {
        manager = msg.sender;
    }

    function enter() public payable {
        require(msg.value == .02 ether);
        players.push(payable(msg.sender));
    }

    function random() private view returns (uint256) {
        return
            uint256(
                keccak256(
                    abi.encodePacked(block.difficulty, block.timestamp, players)
                )
            );
    }

    function pickWinner() public restricted {
        index = random() % players.length;
        players[index].transfer(address(this).balance);
        players = new address payable[](0);
    }

    modifier restricted() {
        require(msg.sender == manager);
        _;
    }

    function getPlayers() public view returns (address payable[] memory) {
        return players;
    }
}
```

On react project, I web3.js file. This is in charged to inject a Web3 object from Metamask, that's the reason I installed web3 module with npm and I imported on this file.

```
import Web3 from "web3";

const web3 = new Web3(window.web3.currentProvider);

export default web3;
```

I also have a lottery.js file, this is in charged of loading the smart contract data created after it was deployed on Ganache local network, this data corresponds to the ABI and the contract address.

```
import web3 from "./web3";

const contractAddress = "0x4fF1731d8eC2776c4202fD2b2145910e4652A500";

const abi = [
    {
        inputs: [],
        stateMutability: "payable",
        type: "constructor",
        payable: true,
    },
    {
        inputs: [],
        name: "manager",
        outputs: [
            {
                internalType: "address",
                name: "",
                type: "address",
            },
        ],
        stateMutability: "view",
        type: "function",
        constant: true,
    },
    {
        inputs: [
            {
                internalType: "uint256",
                name: "",
                type: "uint256",
            },
        ],
        name: "players",
        outputs: [
            {
                internalType: "address payable",
                name: "",
                type: "address",
            },
        ],
        stateMutability: "view",
        type: "function",
        constant: true,
    },
    {
        inputs: [],
        name: "enter",
        outputs: [],
        stateMutability: "payable",
        type: "function",
        payable: true,
    },
    {
        inputs: [],
        name: "pickWinner",
        outputs: [],
        stateMutability: "nonpayable",
        type: "function",
    },
    {
        inputs: [],
        name: "getPlayers",
        outputs: [
            {
                internalType: "address payable[]",
                name: "",
                type: "address[]",
            },
        ],
        stateMutability: "view",
        type: "function",
        constant: true,
    },
];

export default new web3.eth.Contract(abi, contractAddress);
```

Finally, I have an App.js file. This is in charged of creating the App component and implementing functions and events in order to render the single web page.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "./App.css";
import lottery from "./lottery";
import web3 from "./web3";

class App extends Component {
    state = {
        manager: "",
        players: [],
        balance: "",
    };

    async componentDidMount() {
        const players = await lottery.methods.getPlayers().call();
        const manager = await lottery.methods.manager().call();
        const balance = await web3.eth.getBalance(lottery.options.address);

        console.log(players);
        this.setState({ manager, players, balance });
    }

    enter = async (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();

        const accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();

        console.log(this.state.players);
        await lottery.methods.enter().send({
            from: accounts[0],
            value: web3.utils.toWei("0.02", "ether"),
        });
    };

    pickWinner = async () => {
        const accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();

        await lottery.methods.pickWinner().send({
            from: accounts[0],
        });
    };

    render() {
        var rows = [];

        for (var i = 0; i < this.state.players.length; i++) {
            rows.push(
                <label>
                    {" "}
                    <br />
                    Player {i + 1} - {this.state.players[i]}{" "}
                </label>
            );
        }

        return (
            <div className="App">
                <h2 align="center">Lottery Contract</h2>

                <p>
                    This contract is managed by <b>{this.state.manager}</b>. All players
                    are competing to win{" "}
                    <b>{web3.utils.fromWei(this.state.balance, "ether")}</b> ether!
                </p>

                <hr />

                <p>
                    All {this.state.players.length} players are {rows}
                </p>

                <hr />

                <h4>Want to try your luck?</h4>
                <button
                    className="button"
                    style={{ height: 40, width: 150, borderRadius: 10, fontSize: 15 }}
                    onClick={this.enter}
                >
                    {" "}
                    <b>Enter</b>
                </button>

                <hr />

                <h4>Ready to pick a winner?</h4>
                <button
                    className="button"
                    style={{ height: 40, width: 150, borderRadius: 10, fontSize: 15 }}
                    onClick={this.pickWinner}
                >
                    <b>Pick Winner</b>
                </button>

                <hr />
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

When I run `npm start`, I got all these errors:

```
Compiled with problems:X

ERROR in ./node_modules/cipher-base/index.js 3:16-43

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'stream' in '/home/user/lottery-frontend/lottery/node_modules/cipher-base'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "stream": require.resolve("stream-browserify") }'
    - install 'stream-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "stream": false }


ERROR in ./node_modules/eth-lib/lib/bytes.js 9:193-227

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in '/home/user/lottery-frontend/lottery/node_modules/eth-lib/lib'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "crypto": require.resolve("crypto-browserify") }'
    - install 'crypto-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "crypto": false }


ERROR in ./node_modules/ethereumjs-util/dist.browser/account.js 39:31-48

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'assert' in '/home/user/lottery-frontend/lottery/node_modules/ethereumjs-util/dist.browser'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "assert": require.resolve("assert/") }'
    - install 'assert'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "assert": false }


ERROR in ./node_modules/ethereumjs-util/dist.browser/address.js 14:31-48

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'assert' in '/home/user/lottery-frontend/lottery/node_modules/ethereumjs-util/dist.browser'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "assert": require.resolve("assert/") }'
    - install 'assert'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "assert": false }


ERROR in ./node_modules/ethereumjs-util/dist.browser/object.js 14:31-48

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'assert' in '/home/user/lottery-frontend/lottery/node_modules/ethereumjs-util/dist.browser'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "assert": require.resolve("assert/") }'
    - install 'assert'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "assert": false }


ERROR in ./node_modules/web3-eth-accounts/lib/index.js 31:74-91

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in '/home/user/lottery-frontend/lottery/node_modules/web3-eth-accounts/lib'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "crypto": require.resolve("crypto-browserify") }'
    - install 'crypto-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "crypto": false }


ERROR in ./node_modules/web3-eth-accounts/node_modules/eth-lib/lib/bytes.js 7:193-227

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in '/home/user/lottery-frontend/lottery/node_modules/web3-eth-accounts/node_modules/eth-lib/lib'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "crypto": require.resolve("crypto-browserify") }'
    - install 'crypto-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "crypto": false }


ERROR in ./node_modules/web3-providers-http/lib/index.js 30:11-26

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'http' in '/home/user/lottery-frontend/lottery/node_modules/web3-providers-http/lib'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "http": require.resolve("stream-http") }'
    - install 'stream-http'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "http": false }


ERROR in ./node_modules/web3-providers-http/lib/index.js 32:12-28

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'https' in '/home/user/lottery-frontend/lottery/node_modules/web3-providers-http/lib'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "https": require.resolve("https-browserify") }'
    - install 'https-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "https": false }


ERROR in ./node_modules/web3-providers-ws/lib/helpers.js 11:12-26

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'url' in '/home/user/lottery-frontend/lottery/node_modules/web3-providers-ws/lib'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "url": require.resolve("url/") }'
    - install 'url'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "url": false }


ERROR in ./node_modules/xhr2-cookies/dist/xml-http-request.js 37:11-26

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'http' in '/home/user/lottery-frontend/lottery/node_modules/xhr2-cookies/dist'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "http": require.resolve("stream-http") }'
    - install 'stream-http'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "http": false }


ERROR in ./node_modules/xhr2-cookies/dist/xml-http-request.js 39:12-28

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'https' in '/home/user/lottery-frontend/lottery/node_modules/xhr2-cookies/dist'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "https": require.resolve("https-browserify") }'
    - install 'https-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "https": false }


ERROR in ./node_modules/xhr2-cookies/dist/xml-http-request.js 41:9-22

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'os' in '/home/user/lottery-frontend/lottery/node_modules/xhr2-cookies/dist'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "os": require.resolve("os-browserify/browser") }'
    - install 'os-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "os": false }


ERROR in ./node_modules/xhr2-cookies/dist/xml-http-request.js 43:10-24

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'url' in '/home/user/lottery-frontend/lottery/node_modules/xhr2-cookies/dist'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "url": require.resolve("url/") }'
    - install 'url'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "url": false }
```

I've solved them by doing what the messages suggested. So I installed these packages: stream-browserify, https-browserify, os-browserify, crypto-browserify, stream-http, url, assert. After that, I changed the webpack.config.js from the path `node_modules>>react-scripts>>config>>webpack.config.js` by adding the below:

```
...
module.exports = function (webpackEnv) {
  ...
  return {
   ...
        resolve: {
      fallback: {"stream": require.resolve("stream-browserify"), "crypto": require.resolve("crypto-browserify"), "assert": require.resolve("assert/"), "http": require.resolve("stream-http"), "https": require.resolve("https-browserify"), "url": require.resolve("url/"), "os": require.resolve("os-browserify/browser"), "url": require.resolve("url/")},
     ...
    }
  }
}
...
```

And I got the webpack compiled but I got nothing renders on localhost:3000, 22 warnings and failures at parsing source maps, like this (the log is so long so I'm just showing some of it):

```
Compiled with warnings.

Failed to parse source map from '/home/user/lottery-frontend/lottery/node_modules/@ethersproject/abi/src.ts/_version.ts' file: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/user/lottery-frontend/lottery/node_modules/@ethersproject/abi/src.ts/_version.ts'

Failed to parse source map from '/home/user/lottery-frontend/lottery/node_modules/@ethersproject/abi/src.ts/abi-coder.ts' file: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/user/lottery-frontend/lottery/node_modules/@ethersproject/abi/src.ts/abi-coder.ts'

...

Search for the keywords to learn more about each warning.
To ignore, add // eslint-disable-next-line to the line before.

assets by path static/js/*.js 4.96 MiB
  asset static/js/bundle.js 4.95 MiB [emitted] (name: main) 1 related asset
  asset static/js/node_modules_web-vitals_dist_web-vitals_js.chunk.js 6.92 KiB [emitted] 1 related asset
asset index.html 1.67 KiB [emitted]
asset asset-manifest.json 458 bytes [emitted]
cached modules 4.62 MiB [cached] 591 modules
runtime modules 31.5 KiB 17 modules
javascript modules 8.85 KiB
  ./src/App.js 6.56 KiB [code generated]
  ./src/lottery.js 2.28 KiB [built] [code generated]

WARNING in ./node_modules/@ethersproject/abi/lib.esm/_version.js
Module Warning (from ./node_modules/source-map-loader/dist/cjs.js):
Failed to parse source map from '/home/user/lottery-frontend/lottery/node_modules/@ethersproject/abi/src.ts/_version.ts' file: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/user/lottery-frontend/lottery/node_modules/@ethersproject/abi/src.ts/_version.ts'
 @ ./node_modules/@ethersproject/abi/lib.esm/fragments.js 6:0-37 7:26-33
 @ ./node_modules/@ethersproject/abi/lib.esm/index.js 3:0-117 6:0-204 6:0-204 6:0-204 6:0-204 6:0-204 6:0-204
 @ ./node_modules/web3-eth-abi/lib/index.js 28:21-59 30:16-55
 @ ./node_modules/web3-eth/lib/index.js 47:10-33
 @ ./node_modules/web3/lib/index.js 34:10-29
 @ ./src/web3.js 3:0-24 4:17-21
 @ ./src/App.js 30:0-26 44:29-49 48:15-31 53:29-49 63:26-45 106:20-38
 @ ./src/index.js 7:0-24 11:33-36
...

22 warnings have detailed information that is not shown.
Use 'stats.errorDetails: true' resp. '--stats-error-details' to show it.

webpack 5.70.0 compiled with 22 warnings in 2515 ms
```

One last thing, for injecting the web3 object, I use Metamask.

I wonder what the problem is and how can I make my app renders on localhost:3000.

Comment: it cra issue: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/pull/11752 try to set up a webpack

Comment: @Yilmaz, it works adding ```...
"scripts": { "start": "GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false react-scripts start",  },``` on package.json in order to rid of warning messages. But the application continues without rendering on http://localhost:3000/. I should see something like this: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1uLICxoruwaaSBQKdTBlSA_kbLVne6B43/view?usp=sharing

Comment: can you check console. sometimes webpack does not show error, but console shows issue

Comment: @Yilmaz, do you mean to this:https://drive.google.com/file/d/1j47Lb3d_xF8V1zM3s-impRiMTV_iraxI/view?usp=sharing, (sorry for showing an image for the console log, but I thought this was better to show like this on a comment)

Comment: Nope, chrome developer tools. CTRL + SHIFT +C then click on console tab

Comment: @Yilmaz, ok sure! https://drive.google.com/file/d/1gwyc0UuXLAm0RvOsBM81B43yC8jXVHfG/view?usp=sharing

Comment: your webpack set up has issue. either check this for webpack https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70559396/webpack-breaking-change or this for cra https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70472965/web3-issue-react-application-not-compiling/70512623#70512623

Comment: @Yilmaz, thanks. This finally works! https://github.com/ChainSafe/web3.js#troubleshooting-and-known-issues

Comment: great. good luck.